# Плавная анимация блоков

Tags: javascript, css

Мне нужно что бы при наведении на block1 появлялся drop__block1 c скоростью .5s а пропадал с скоростью 3s.

```css
    .main__block {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .block1 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .block1:hover .drop__block1 {
      display: block;
    }
    .block2 {
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .block2:hover .drop__block2 {
      display: block;
    }
    .drop__block1 {
      background-color: blue;
      display: none;
    }
    .drop__block2 {
      background-color: tomato;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main__block">
      <div class="block1">hello
        <div class="drop__block1">aaaaaaaa</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block2">world
      <div class="drop__block2">bbbbbbbb</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.block__drop {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s linear opacity, 0.3s linear visibility;
}

.block_1 .block__drop {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block_2 .block__drop {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.block:hover .block__drop {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.5s linear opacity, 0.5s linear visibility;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__block">
  <div class="block block_1">hello
    <div class="block__drop">aaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block block_2">world
    <div class="block__drop">bbbbbbbb</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Для удобства, я бы использовал CSS переменные:

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.block__drop {
  --hoverOut: 0.3s;
  --hoverOver: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: var(--hoverOut);
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
}

.block_1 .block__drop {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block_2 .block__drop {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.block:hover .block__drop {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-duration: var(--hoverOver);
}
```

```html
<div class="main__block">
  <div class="block block_1">hello
    <div class="block__drop">aaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block block_2">world
    <div class="block__drop">bbbbbbbb</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое)